# Using Access 2003 ADP/Project files to access SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, adp

We use Access Project files to connect with SQL Server.

Our SQL Server 2000 has been upgraded to SQL Server 2005 and now my project files are reporting an incompatibility and the error "This recordset is not updatable" when trying to modify data.

So:

1) Will upgrading to Access 2007 and then creating project files solve this problem?

2) If upgrading to the latest version of Access is not an option, is there a plugin or Microsoft converter I can download to allow Access 2003 to open SQL Server 2005 databases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you update to Access 2007 then the ADP project files should be compatible.

Other options are:

- Dowloading [SQL Server 2005
  Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).  This
  can be used for creating tables etc.
  but has no form building
  functionality.
- Continue using Access 2003 but create
  linked tables in a MDB file.